# Why I am getting 'no file chosen' error while uploading image in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Here is my codes and I tried all methods but none of them work :(
models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class Review(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' | ' + self.job[:50]

    class Meta():
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

forms.py file

```
from django import forms

from .models import Review


class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView

from .forms import ReviewForm
from .models import Review



class ReviewView(ListView):
    model = Review
    template_name = 'testimonals/home.html'


def WriteReview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    form = ReviewForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "testimonals/create_post.html", context)
```

html file

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[Here is problem but I fill all fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPCJs.png)

[Here is result which I added by admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qWal.png)

Comment: You should specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>` tag.